# Get all http headers

Tags: google-apps-script

[HTTPResponse.getHeaders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_httpresponse#getHeaders) returns a key-value map. The problem is when there are multiple headers with the same name (e.g. there is often multiple 'set-cookie' headers), as you only get access to the one defined last.

How do I access all the headers of the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `getAllHeaders()` which returns an array of values for each key instead (precisely for this reason).

Comment: That's the one. Thanks. I thought there must be a method for this. I've seen it popup on auto complete now. Why isn't this method documented on the api website? As without playing I don't instantly know that the type of Object returned is an array, as you say.

Comment: We are aggressively redocumenting the APIs but it's not done yet.

Comment: This method is now included in our documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getAllHeaders()